# What does "return [0]" mean?

Tags: python

What does `return [0]` mean? Is it the same as `return 0`?

```
class Solution:
    def smallerNumbersThanCurrent(self, nums):
        if(len(nums)<2):
            return([0])
        l=[]
        lst=list(nums)
        lst.sort()
        for i in nums:
            a=lst.index(i)
            l.append(a)
        return(l)
```

Comment: This just a list with one item: the integer zero

Comment: What does `[0,1,2]` mean? What does `[0,1]` mean? Answering that, ask yourself again, what does `[0]` mean?

Comment: `0` is the integer zero. `[0]` is a list that contains a single element.

Comment: You can easily see that `[0]` and `0` are two entirely different values. `type([0])` and `type(0)` differ, and `[0] == 0` is false.

Comment: The code looks more complicated than it has to. `if` and `return` are not functions, so you can drop the parentheses. `if(len(nums)<2):` should be written as `if len(nums) < 2:` and `return([0])` should be `return [0]`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This would mean that you are returning a list with one element in it, that is 0.

```
return([0]) ---> [0] ---> this is list

return(0) ---> 0 ---> this is integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'type' function to check what kind of object it is...

```
>>> print([0])
[0]
>>> type([0])
<class 'list'>
>>> [0][0]
0
>>> type([0][0])
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

Above, we see [0] is a list.

Anyway, the real question why someone wants return a one-item-list with zero in a function...